# Why a button jumps to a new line after a div element?

Tags: html, css

Can you explain why a button jumps to a new line after a `<div>` element? It is inline element, right? why then doesn't it stay inline?
I can't put that button inside the `<div>` because that `<div>` constantly updates with Jquery, so it will remove (overwrite) it. Is there a way to make the button not to jump to a new line after a `<div>` ?

```html
<div >some text</div>
<button>MyButton</button>
```

Comment: `div`s are block level and always put a line break before the next element. If you want the div and button to line up you should use `display:inline` in your CSS. There are multiple ways to lay this out.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap both elements and add `display: flex` to the wrapper.

[Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>some text</div>
  <button>MyButton</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> why button jumps to a new line after a  element?

that is because **div** by default is a block element (display:block) which means it starts on a new line and takes the whole width and hence the button next to it is displayed on the next line.
To change this behavior, use css to change **display** property of the div to **inline**.

For more details [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

div are not inline elements, they are block elements.

The best way to have a div element as an inline element is to give it a style `display:inline` in your stylesheet.

Also are you using Jquery on all div elements? How about using a `class` or an ID instead?

Answer (score 1):

`button` and `span` are inline elements. while `div` is a block level element.

`1.)` for `<span>a</span><span>b</span>`,

`a` will sit in the first line & `normal document flow` stays on the same line as `a` and `b` are enclosed within the `span` element which is an `inline` element. So, `b` follows the `horizontal flow` and sits after `a` in the same line.

giving output as,

```
ab
```

`2.)` for `<div>a</div><span>b</span>` & `<div>a</div><div>b</div>`,

`a` will sit in the first line & `normal document flow` goes to the next line because of the `vertical stacking nature` of the first `div` element. So, `b` follows the `vertical flow` and sits in the new line.

giving output as,

```
a
b
```

`3.)` for `<span>a</span><div>b</div>`,

`a` will sit in the first line & `normal document flow` goes to the next line because of the `vertical stacking nature` of the adjacent `div` element. So, `b` follows the `vertical flow` and sits in the new line.

giving output as,

```
a
b
```

`*)` `Bonus`:

`Statement 1`: Block level element starts on a new line.

`Statement 2`: Block level element takes the full width of its parent element no matter how small the content is.

`Statement 3`: By default block level elements will consume all of the space in the inline direction. If we give them a width, they will continue to lay out one below the other - even if there would be space for them to be side by side.

Now, all these three `statements` are defined to maintain the `vertical stacking nature` of the `block level elements`.

This is the prime logic behind the scenes...